# How to get input box value into php variable without submitting and without ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a hidden input, as follows -

```
<input type='hidden' id='question_number' name='question_number' value='100'/>
```

**I need the value of `question_number` into a php variable, without submitting.** 
I know that in jquery it can be done by -

```
var q_no = $('#question_number').val();
```

but I don't know how to send it to php variable.

Also I don't want to create a new file just to get the 'question_number' by ajax.
I don't know if this is possible without submitting and without ajax.

p.s. I found a related question, but I couldn't not found working answer there.

**Edit-1.** I know that PHP is server-side and jquery/javascript is client side, before posting this question. But, I was thinking, if a php code, can search through entire page of this particular input type, and then parse its value. I am NOT a php expert, so I can't construct this on my own. I need this value in PHP for further coding.

**Edit-2.** Please read Edit 1, before negative voting.

Comment: If you're not willing to send the data to the server how would you expect the server side script to be aware of that date?

Comment: @DavidThomas Although I have edited my question for your question (Edit-1), but  as derdida replied, that even Edit-1 is NOT possible. I think i will have to delete my question, else I will lose all of my points, just because I was curious to find, if any solution exist.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. Javascript runs on client, and PHP runs on the server.

Comment: I read the same, before posting this question. I was thinking, if a php code, can search through entire page of this particular input type, and then parse its value. I am NOT a php expert, so I can't construct this on my own.

Comment: This could be possible if your page runs on YOUR local Server. So the HTML Files are on your local Filesystem and you can read them by PHP. But only for your local Browser.

Answer (score -1):

As derdida said, you are missing the point as client side coding (ex: jQuery) is completely different from server side coding (ex: PHP). You should search for "client server side code" on Google and start from there ;)